# Defining business rule in code

Tags: oop, business-rules

A fellow programmer told me that I shouldn't put **Business Rule** in JSPs. This really confused me.

I'm really having a hard time understanding this. I mean I don't know how can I identify which in the code is the **Business rule**.

**Questions:**

1. What is really a business rule?( I know I can search this on google but can you give me a simple example? )
2. How can I identify business rule in the code ( an example would be great )

Answer (score 5):

Business rule is a criterion used in business operations to guide behaviour, shape judgements and make decisions.

What I see is most of the times, a confusion between different types of logic, and they all are called business rules by mistake. There are many reasons that you should not implement business rules into your source code. Generally, your application should take care of different types of logic: Application Logic and Business Rule. When you separate these from each other, then you allow business rules to be updated independently, with no application code change by business people. For example, when a tax rate is changed, business can update the tax rule without need to ask IT team (developers).

So in your question, if you still keep the business rule in JSP codes, then there still is dependency to developers (and IT) so that's not much beneficial from what I just mentioned. However structuring in a better way in your code, would be beneficial in long run of the project, so developers will be update them easier.

If you want to extract them totally from your source code, and let them be managed out side of your source (JSP) you need a business rule management system (BRMS). One component of a BRMS is a [Business Rule Engine (BRE)](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/business-rule-engine-bre/) which allows you to execute the [business rules that are modelled in different forms](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/modeling-business-rule-and-decision/).
When we are talking about BRMS, it is not only the execution (BRE) aspect  of it but also other capabilities like, standard modeling language and authoring, debugging, testing, version control, deployment and hosting as a service (REST), security and permission control and so on... therefore a BRMS solution should cover the whole lifecycle of business rules.

Regarding to identifying them in your code, IMHO, in an existing application, it is not easy to identify and extract the business rules out. It really depends on the complexity of application domain and how well it is written. Pick one specific scenario, sit with your BA, define the business need and requirement of the implemented scenario, check if a logic is application logic, or business related logic. [Here is an example of how business rule can be separated from source code](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/separation-of-concerns/).

Answer (score 3):

Like much else in programming something that started of as a sensible guideline has mutated into an ill-defined rule and a stick for pedants to hit the innocent programmer with.

Firstly no one agrees what a business logic is. At one end of the scale you have people like @Arash who think of a business rule as something specified by the business and under their control like the exact rate for sales tax. On the other hand some people think any logic at all like checking the sql return code qualifies as business logic. And if you are implementing a system for a charity hospital how can there by any "business" rules at all.

For simplicity and clarity I would urge people to stick with the following definition. "Rules specified by the requester/customer of the system" so when your project sponsor says "calculate sales tax like this" its a business rule everything else is an implementation detail.

Secondly while in most cases it makes sense to keep the presentation (as in formatting the screen, populating pull downs etc.) separate from the fetching the data and calculating the numbers its not always that simple. What if there is a business rule "don't let the customer see the sales commission numbers"? You now have to format the screen differently if there is a customer present, a rule which is easiest to implement in the "presentation logic". Or "use the Bloomberg color scheme that my traders understand" you code jump through lots of hoops to implement "green for up, red for down, white for unchanged" in this "business logic" back end or you could have some simple and easy to understand code in the "presentation logic".

So unless you have a really good reason to keep your JSP code simple and concerned only with formatting and presentation. But if there is a good reason to put logic there then just do it. A simple trick is to ask yourself "how easy would it be to implement this as a voice only call center application"

Answer (score -2):

Business rule is simply a programming logic which is used to process data extracted from database.

Business rule need not to be implemented using JSP. It should be created using Java programming logics and then JSP should be used to display data.